# PS4 controller not connecting

Tags: usb, 18.10, input-devices

It just glows and blinks orange. I did connect a friend's ps4 controller this way before mine, and it worked, but mine's doesn't.

I don't have bluetooth or an adapter to use or test. I have pressed the small button on the back of the controller while plugged but it didn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.10.

[Found this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/9bs0hb/playstation_4_dualshock_4_gamepad_isnt_working/) and I'm getting the same thing.

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-13-generic
$ tail -f /var/log/kern.log
Dec 26 19:55:47 PC kernel: [ 2442.627095] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 15
Dec 26 19:59:17 PC kernel: [ 2652.069256] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
Dec 26 19:59:17 PC kernel: [ 2652.218539] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=05c4, bcdDevice= 1.00
Dec 26 19:59:17 PC kernel: [ 2652.218546] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 26 19:59:17 PC kernel: [ 2652.218550] usb 3-10: Product: Wireless Controller
Dec 26 19:59:17 PC kernel: [ 2652.218554] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: Sony Computer Entertainment
Dec 26 19:59:22 PC kernel: [ 2657.377374] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0018: failed to retrieve feature report 0x81 with the DualShock 4 MAC address
Dec 26 19:59:22 PC kernel: [ 2657.377620] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0018: hidraw17: USB HID v81.11 Gamepad [Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
Dec 26 19:59:22 PC kernel: [ 2657.377623] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0018: failed to claim input
Dec 26 20:01:08 PC kernel: [ 2763.516279] usb 3-10: USB disconnect, device number 16
```

As soon as I plug it in:

```
Dec 26 20:01:55 PC kernel: [ 2810.533011] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Dec 26 20:01:55 PC kernel: [ 2810.682396] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=05c4, bcdDevice= 1.00
Dec 26 20:01:55 PC kernel: [ 2810.682403] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 26 20:01:55 PC kernel: [ 2810.682407] usb 3-10: Product: Wireless Controller
Dec 26 20:01:55 PC kernel: [ 2810.682411] usb 3-10: Manufacturer: Sony Computer Entertainment
Dec 26 20:02:00 PC kernel: [ 2815.845170] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0019: failed to retrieve feature report 0x81 with the DualShock 4 MAC address
Dec 26 20:02:00 PC kernel: [ 2815.845404] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0019: hidraw18: USB HID v81.11 Gamepad [Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
Dec 26 20:02:00 PC kernel: [ 2815.845407] sony 0003:054C:05C4.0019: failed to claim input
```

`lsusb` shows my friend's controller even when not connected.

```
Bus 003 Device 018: ID 054c:05c4 Sony Corp. DualShock 4
```

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue when connecting via a wire on Ubuntu 20.04. Bluetooth works fine though.